# Correlated Subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, correlated-subquery

```
Create Table NEW AS (
SELECT
"60+ DAYS",
"30-60 DAYS",
"7-30 DAYS",
( select ("60+ DAYS"+"30-60 DAYS"+"7-30 DAYS")
  from Schema.Table
  Where Schema.Table.Column1 like '%X%'
    and (Schema.Table.Column2 like '%Y%' or Schema.Table.Column2 like '%Y%')
) as "TOTAL",
"ROLE OWNERS NAME",
"ROLE OWNERS EMAIL",
 FROM Schema.Table
Where Schema.Table.Column1 like '%X%'
  and (Schema.Table.Column2 like '%Y%' or Schema.Table.Column2 like '%Y%' )
ORDER BY "60+ DAYS",
         "30-60 DAYS",
         "7-30 DAYS" desc;
```

Can someone advise me on how I might correlate my subquery,

"60+ DAYS",
"30-60 DAYS",
"7-30 DAYS",
"ROLE OWNERS NAME",
"ROLE OWNERS EMAIL",
X,
Y

are all columns in the same table, and I need to sum the values of the first three columns row per row and append them as TOTAL to the query result. Any help is appreciated, using SQL Plus, 11g rack

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense. You are selecting from `SSDASHBOARD_DBO.RODATA`, but the `WHERE` clause is on `Schema.Table`. If the two are connected, please provide the foreign key column(s).

Comment: I just didn't pull the name out, edited

Comment: Those are **really** horrible column names. You should think about changing them to something that is easier to use

Comment: I have better column names, just for the sake of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand what you are trying to do, but what about removing the subquery?

```
SELECT
  "60+ DAYS",
  "30-60 DAYS",
  "7-30 DAYS",
  ("60+ DAYS" + "30-60 DAYS" + "7-30 DAYS") as "TOTAL",
  ...
```